# my query take a long time to run ,why?

Tags: sql

I have a query that returns c.a 1800 records( not many) but It takes long time to ran (10 seconds) but I can not understand why?
this is my query that takes a long time:

```
SELECT tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Konzept AS KonzeptID, tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Funktion,
    tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Version, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.ID,
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Fehlerpfad_Kommentar AS Kommentar, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Fehlerpfadname, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Fehlerpfad_CDT, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Fehlerpfad_Kommentar, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.symptombasiert, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Beschreibung_vorhanden, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Max_Pfad, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Max_Info, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Max_Status, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Max_Strategie, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Max_Prüfplan, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Min_Pfad, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Min_Info, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Min_Status, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Min_Strategie, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Min_Prüfplan, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Sig_Pfad, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Sig_Info, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Sig_Status,
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Sig_Strategie, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Sig_Prüfplan, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Plaus_Pfad, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Plaus_Info, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Plaus_Status, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Plaus_Strategie, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Plaus_Prüfplan, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Beschreibung_allgemein, 
    qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Funktionsname        
FROM tb_KonzeptFunktionen RIGHT JOIN qryFunktionen_Übersicht 
    ON tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Funktion = qryFunktionen_Übersicht.Funktionsname
WHERE (((tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Konzept)=[Formulare]![frm_Fahrzeug]![ID]))
```

and this is another related query to above query:

```
SELECT tbFunktionen_Übersicht.*, 
    tbFunktionen.Funktionsname, 
    tbFunktionen.Funktionsbeschreibung, 
    tbFunktionen.diagnoserelevant, 
    tbFunktionen.ID AS FunktionsID
FROM tbFunktionen_Übersicht INNER JOIN tbFunktionen 
    ON tbFunktionen_Übersicht.Funktion = tbFunktionen.ID
ORDER BY tbFunktionen.Funktionsname, tbFunktionen_Übersicht.Fehlerpfadname;
```

I added an index to the fields that appear in **ORDER** oder **JOINS** but no effect
Would you please help me if possible?

---

Please refer to this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/8193aa29-9835-48a9-ae1c-512e95b15304/#94c6803e-5a09-4bb2-be5f-3f3b85c2d0f4),hier you can find the answer

Comment: Do you have index on tbFunktionen_Übersicht.Funktion and tbFunktionen.ID, please create them if missing.

Comment: yes Iput indexes on these fields

Comment: what are the types of these fields used in joining condition and where clause. How much time the second query is taking?

Comment: 10 seconds and some of them are text and another part is number

Answer (score 0):

for me PDO brought improvement in my sql query's: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

```
    //SQL-HANDLING*******************************************************//
//*********************************************************************//
//General Example-----------------
//$sqlHandling = new sqlHandling;
//$sqlHandling->connectSQL($sqlArray['host'], $sqlArray['user'],$sqlArray['pass'], $sqlArray['dbName']);
    //$tableNameArray = $sqlHandling->showTablesSQL($sqlHandling->dbh);
class sqlHandling{

    //PDO - Object/ callItOutside with: $sqlClass->dbh
    public $dbh = null;

//connectDataBase-------------------//
    //-----------------
    //example: $dbh = connectSQL('localhost','admin','1admin','test');
    //start transaction
    //$dbh->beginTransaction();
    //-----------------
    //end transaction
    //$dbh->commit();
    //$dbh = null;
    //-----------------
    //1:SQL-Location
    function connectSQL($host, $user, $pass, $dbname){
        //endPrevTransaction
        if($this->dbh != null){
            $this->dbh->commit();
            $this->dbh = null;
        }
        //establish connection
        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $pass);
            $this->dbh->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
            return $this->dbh;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print 'Error!: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>';
            die();
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
//createColumnSQL-------------------//
    //example: createColumnSQL($dbh, 'backupexample', array('SomeName1 VARCHAR(30)', 'SomeName2 VARCHAR(30)', 'SomeName3 VARCHAR(30)', 'SomeName4 VARCHAR(30)'));
    //1:PDO connection/2:table/3:array holding columns
    function createColumnSQL($dbh, $table, $columns){
        //cicle through each array
        foreach($columns as $tempColumn){
            //set query
            $query = 'ALTER TABLE `'.$table.'` ADD COLUMN '.$tempColumn;
            //send the query
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
            //send the data
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

This is only a working example for my PDO sqlHandling Class. I know retrieveAllValues won't help you further but you may adopt this code for your use.

MFG